# Set windows environment variable in a shell script in git bash

Tags: windows, bash, environment-variables

I want to use a bash script to set a windows environment variable and after running this script, I should be able to read the windows env variable with echo $var. Unfortunately this doesnt worked for me.

```
echo -n password:
read -s password
echo

export var=http://username:${password}@domain.com:8080
```

Comment: Not a `git`  question

Comment: If you are calling this script from a `bash` session, you would need to `source` it because, otherwise, the script is running on a _new_ bash session (where the value is being set) and which dies as soon as the script finishes (and it doesn't affect the parent session where you called the script from).